# Is the set of all functions a finite set?

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory

Suppose $A$ and $B$ are finite sets. Let $\mathcal{F} = \{ f | f: A \to B \}$. We want to prove that $\mathcal{F}$ is finite

The idea is to construct a function $F$ that is a bijection from $\mathcal{F}$ to some section of positive integers $S_k = \{ 1,..., k \}$.

We know that there are bijections $g_1 : A \to S_n $ and $g_2: B \to S_m$

Well, we know that the set of all functions is of the form $B^A$ but I ${\bf can't}$ visualize why this is so, but we can define:

$$ F(f) = ( f(1),f(2),...,f(n) ) $$

but this may not work at all. Any hints/suggestions?

Comment: Perhaps count the number of ways to map to some subset of $B$.

Comment: What do you mean by "we know that the set of all functions is of the form $B^A$"? What is the "form" here? $B^A$ is just a notation. You could as well denote it by $A\to B$ or any other way using the two letters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, number the elements of $A$ and $B$ as $A=\{a_1,a_2,\ldots, a_{|A|}\}$, $B=\{b_1,b_2,\ldots, b_{|B|}\}$. This is another way of writing your bijections $g_1,g_2$.

Now, consider where a function $f:A\rightarrow B$ could send an element $a_i\in A$. Each of these elements could be sent to any element of $B$. One could write $f(a_i)=b_j$.

How many distinct ways are there to form such an $f$? Each of the $|A|$ elements has the option to go to one of $|B|$ locations.

Can you see how to build an $F$ to map each $f$ to an element in $\{1,\ldots , |B|^{|A|}\}$?

Comment: The a_i's and b_i's may not be ordered

Comment: @Theoneandonly: You can always order a finite set. Even without the axiom of choice.

Comment: @Theoneandonly: You’re given that $A$ and $B$ are finite, so there are positive integers $n_A$ and $n_B$ and bijections $h_A:A\to[n_A]$ and $h_B:B\to[n_B]$, where $[n]=\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$. These bijection in effect order $A$ and $B$: you can set $a_i=h_A^{-1}(i)$, for instance. (You should also deal with the cases in which $A$ or $B$ is $\varnothing$, but those are easy.)

Comment: Thanks prof. Scott! maybe you can write this as an answer so I can award you the points to you sir, thanks sir

Comment: @Theoneandonly: That’s okay: BeefSupreme’s answer is pretty good, and I’m perfectly happy to see it rewarded.